# CSS Navbar - Positioning UL within a DIV

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've been trying to create a pretty basic CSS navbar, comprised of a *"navbar"* container div, and within that a *"logo"* div and a *"menu"* div.

However, I seem to have run into some trouble with getting the *"menu"* div (which contains an unordered list of links) to nest within the *"navbar"* container div.

Perhaps I'm missing something very simple, but I've tried doing some Googling and can't seem to find a solution to this issue.

I did see a tutorial that showed how to create a similar type of navbar using only an unordered list, but given that I'm also looking to have a logo and potentially other elements in the navbar, I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Please see below for the HTML and CSS that I've been working with. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```css
body{
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

.navbar{
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 background: #b4cef7;
}

.logo{
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 width: 50px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar ul{
 list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar ul li{
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 width: 50px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: white;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>Simple CSS Navbar</title>

 <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

 </head>
 <body>
  
 <div class="navbar">

  <div class="logo">
   <i class="fas fa-coffee fa-2x"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a set height on the navbar and a [block level](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) element, forcing the navbar to a new line.

There's many ways you could have the elements on the same line, such as floating or displaying `inline-block`.

Here's a simple demo of using `inline-block`:

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #b4cef7;
}

.navbar>* {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar ul li {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="navbar">

  <div class="logo">
    <i class="fas fa-coffee fa-2x"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

There isn't generally a option you *should* use, be it `inline-block`, floating, or flexbox; it really just depends on your preferences and target browsers.